# How to add border to selected item in Bottom Navigation View in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I have a bottom navigation view, need to implement border around the icon(like rectangle) on every selected item. Code is below. Thank you.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/yellowLanus"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navbar_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navbar_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

rectangle.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="12px"/>
    <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

navbar_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checkable="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rectangle"
         />
    <item android:color="@color/black"  />
</selector>
```